# rails - find_by_sql: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` for the code below...any ideas?

```
@user_industry = current_user.industry

@industries = Listing.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE industry = ?", @user_industry)
```

Comment: had the same issue. The answer below helped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the same string replacement as with AR find

`Listing.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM listings WHERE industry = ?", @user_industry])`

[API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql)